# convert failing to draw text on image after previous edit of simple PNG, other draws work fine

Tags: imagemagick, png

Source image file: http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/ios7v2/256/Music-Set-Cornet-icon.png

I want to shift the image up in an automated fashion:

```
convert -page +0-24 Music-Set-Cornet-icon.png \
 -background none -flatten PNG32:cornet_shifted.png
```

This works fine. Problem is that if I try to resize and draw text on the image it fails. But It works fine on the unmodified PNG file.

```
convert cornet_shifted.png -resize 192x192 \
   -fill white -stroke white -font Helvetica -pointsize 48 \
   -draw "text 35,150 'Hello'" \
   PNG32:cornet_shifted_withtext.png
```

So far, I've spent 2 hours trying to determine why this problem happens.  The text just doesn't get rendered. If you change the source file to the original (without the first run of convert) PNG - works great.

Also of note: Drawing lines or even drawing another PNG on top works great. It is only text that behaves this way. I'm on: mageMagick 6.7.7-10 2013-12-15 Q16

Comment: I get a correct image with ImageMagick 6.8.8-7. Have you tried changing -background 'none' to 'purple' to see the text better? The text is drawn inside the transparent area.

Comment: yha, I changed the color. I'll try to update version. Thank you.